# Make the viewport color match the color for the shader automatically

Tags: materials

In cycles is there any way to change the viewport color and the material color at the same time. When I change the material color I have to go down in the viewport select the I dropper match the color. Is there way to change both colors at once.

[image]

Comment: Just don't click *Use Nodes* instantly when creating a new material. At this stage you can change both colors simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. You could use the Material view to match the colors but that asks a lot more from your computer.
I did find a relevant script, but havent tested it myself. I just manually edit the colors :)
http://blendervisionpro.blogspot.be/2014/12/copy-cycles-color-to-viewport.html

Comment: Save time for mean time but it can be more quick if it would change at same time not go below again and click the copy view port button look similar like i dropper